# Why i cannot generate a tabs component using "ionic generate tabs ..." command in version 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to add tab-menu component to an existing ionic project .
PS: my app already have login/registration/logout setup
But when I run `ionic generate tabs` ionic CLI respondes by the following :

```
>ionic g tabs
[ERROR] tabs is not a known feature.

        Use npx ng g --help to list available types of features.
```

moreover : when I try to run `ionic g --help` I got this list of available features to generate :

```
ionic generate - Create Pages, Components, & Angular Features

    Automatically create framework features with Ionic Generate. This command uses the Angular CLI to generate features
    such as pages, components, directives, services, and more.

    - For a full list of available types, use npx ng g --help
    - For a list of options for a types, use npx ng g <type> --help

    You can specify a path to nest your feature within any number of subdirectories. For example, specify a name of
    "pages/New Page" to generate page files at src/app/pages/new-page/.

    To test a generator before file modifications are made, use the --dry-run option.

  Usage:

    $ ionic generate <type> <name>

  Inputs:

    type ............................ The type of feature (e.g. page, component, directive, service)
    name ............................ The name/path of the feature being generated

  Examples:

    $ ionic generate 
    $ ionic generate page
    $ ionic generate page contact
    $ ionic generate component contact/form
    $ ionic generate component login-form --change-detection=OnPush
    $ ionic generate directive ripple --skip-import
    $ ionic generate service api/user
```

I cannot see any command which may generate tabs
Is this related to new version of ionic ?

Comment: That is not a valid command and is not related to the new version of ionic. It is an option to create a PROJECT skeleton with tabs but there has not ever been, to my knowledge, an option to generate tabs as this is not a component, service, or feature, it is simply a design pattern.

Comment: i've been looking to this piece of docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/cli/generate/ but it's v3 :/

Comment: You're looking at ionic 3 docs..... you need to be looking at v6

Comment: my question for now is why ionic v6 don't have an option to generate tabs with CLI except when you start a brand new project based on "tabs"